# calcular cuando inicia y cuando termina la semana

Tags: javascript, nodejs

[image: calculo semanal de lunes a viernes seleccionando solo un dia x]

Como consigo generar una funcion js para hacer el calculo de cuando inicia y cuando termina la semana apartir de un dia que selecciono el usuario. (Tomando en cuenta que la solo de lunes a viernes)

Ejemplo de como se pretende que quede, debe de indicarse que el calculo sera por semana, despues debe de mostrar el calendario para que el usuario seleccione un dia de la semana, cuando el usuario haya indicado el dia, a un costado estara un input en el cual debe de imprimir cual es el inicio y el fin de la semana dependiendo la fecha que selecciono, por ejemplo si selecciono el martes 6 de febrero del 2018 los datos en el input deberan decir **Inicia el 05-02-2018  termina el 09-02-2018**..... Tomando como dia de inicio todos los lunes y los viernes como finales

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una función con el metódo getDay().
Este método te devuelve el día de la semana que elegiste, con base 0 iniciando en lunes.
Es decir lunes = 0, martes = 1, etc...

Por ejemplo, si tu input se llama "fecha"

```
<input type="date" id="fecha">
```

Pues en tu función, la variable diaSemana va a tener el valor de el día que seleccionaron.

```
var fecha = new Date (document.getElementById("fecha").value);            
var diaSemana = fecha.getDay();
```

mas informacion en : [getDay](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/getDay)

En base a esto puedes hacer los cálculos, pero como no muestras nada de código, no hay mucho que te pueda comentar.

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que quieres que la semana inicie desde el Lunes y termine en Domingo, por lo que habría que agregar algunos condicionales dado que getDay() va a devolver el Domingo como primer día, se puede solucionar con un If para que cuando llegue al día Domingo lo tomé como el Séptimo día de la semana. Te sugieron lo siguiente:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="date" id="fechaAnalizar" onChange="weekIF()"><!--Cada vez que se toma una fecha se llama a la funcion-->
<div id="inicio_fin"></div><!--Aqui se imprime el inicio y fin de semana-->
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function weekIF() {

    let div = document.getElementById("inicio_fin");
    let fecha = document.getElementById("fechaAnalizar").value;//Toma el valor de la fecha seleccionado
    var current = new Date(fecha);

    const week = [];
    const weekFormat = [];

    //Controla cual sera el primer dia
    if(current.getDay() == 0){
        current.setDate(((current.getDate() - 7)+1));
    }else{
        current.setDate(((current.getDate() - current.getDay()) + 1));
    }

    week.push(new Date(current));//Agrega el primer dia al array
    current.setDate(current.getDate()+6);//Define el septimo dia
    week.push(new Date(current));//Agrega el ultimo dia al array

    //Aplicar formato deseado a la fecha
    week.forEach((w) => {
        weekFormat.push(moment(w).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
    });

    div.innerHTML = "Inicia el " + weekFormat[0] + " y termina el " + weekFormat[1];
}

</script>
```

Espero te funcione. Quedo atento.

Comment: Hola! he tratado de implementarlo pero me ha marcado un error Uncaught **ReferenceError: semana is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange**                                                                El codigo quedo de la siguiente manera                                                                            div#divC
    p  Fecha  
    input#fechaAnalizar(onChange='weekIF()', type='date')
      div#divD      
    div#inicio_fin                                                                                         function weekIF() {      //contenido de la funcion     }

Comment: Que extraño, cambiaste algún elemento y le colocaste el nombre "semana", porque em el código que te mandé no hay nada que se llame "semana"

Answer (score 0):

La función que toma un valor de tipo Date y devuelve dos valores de tipo Date con las fechas de inicio y fin de la semana (lunes y viernes) es la siguiente:

```
function obtenerInicioYFinSemana(fecha) {
    return {
        inicio: new Date(fecha.getFullYear(), fecha.getMonth(), fecha.getDate() - fecha.getDay() + 1),
        fin: new Date(fecha.getFullYear(), fecha.getMonth(), fecha.getDate() + 5 - fecha.getDay()),
    }
}
```

Ejemplo:

```
obtenerInicioYFinSemana(new Date());
```

Resultado:

```
{
    inicio: Mon Jul 30 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (hora de verano de Europa central), 
    fin: Fri Aug 03 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (hora de verano de Europa central)
}
```

Espero que te sirva.

Un saludo.